# YAML / RosLaunch debug suggestion

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some complicated Roslaunch setups, it can be tough to figure out where a parameter came from.  I've added the following line to each YAML file and it helps me tremendously.  The tag is "source" and the value is the YAML file name:

For example in arm.yaml:
source: arm.yaml

When ROSLaunch executes, you'll see the parameters print out something like this and you can immediately tell where the params came from.

- /arbotix/joints/gripper_joint/max_angle: 0
- /arbotix/joints/gripper_joint/max_speed: 50
- /arbotix/source: arm.yaml
- /arbotix/write_rate: 25

Does anyone see a downside to this or better approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198894/yaml-/-roslaunch-debug-suggestion/) by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2014-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest bringing this up with the [roslaunch SIG](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-roslaunch), where it can be discussed in detail. It may be possible to build a feature like this into roslaunch - a few other additions have been made recently to make launch files easier to understand and debug.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2014-12-05**:
Thanks - will do